# Load sites and files Sencha Touch within app

Tags: file, url, sencha-touch, external

Is it possible in Sencha Touch to open external sites within app (e.g. www.google.com) and what would the syntax be.

And also how to load files (e.g. something.pdf). I know that JQuery Mobile has a 'ShowRemoteSiteExt' function. Does Sencha Touch have anything similar?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an ajax call to populate an element's markup:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    callback: function(response) {
        Ext.fly("element_id").setHTML(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds nice! So I'll just put it in the panel html tag using ''?